# Program that compares elements of two integer arrays a and b, and stores the elements in array c that are in a or b, but not in both a and b

Tags: c

The project I'm working on says to write a program that compares elements of two integer arrays a and b, and stores the elements in array c that are either in a or in b, but not in both a and b. 
For example, array a contains elements {1, 2, 3}, array b contains elements {3, 2, 6, 7}. Array c should contain {1, 6, 7}.

The function should use pointer arithmetic – not subscripting – to visit array elements. In other words, eliminate the loop index variables and all use of the [] operator in the function.

Right now I'm stuck on the user input, but I am not sure how to do the logic either.

```
/* This is what I have so far I'm very stuck and would love guidance.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void find_elements(int *a, int n1, int *b, int n2, int *c, int*size);
int main()
{
    //User inputs length of arrays
    int n1 = 0;
    printf("Enter the length of the first array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    int *a;
    int *p;
    p = a;
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", n1);
    for(p = a; p < a + n1; p++){
        scanf("%d", p);
    }
    printf("asdf");
    int n2 = 0;
    printf("Enter the length of the second array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    int *b;
    int *pb;
    pb = b;
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", n2);
    for(pb = b; pb < b + n2; pb++){
        scanf("%d", pb);
    }
    printf("Output: \n");


}
void find_elements(int *a, int n1, int *b, int n2, int *c, int*size)
{


    return;
}
```

Comment: You did not allocate any memory for your arrays (`a` and `b`). You might need something like `a = malloc(n1 * sizeof(*a))`. Apart from this: What exactly does not work or where do you get a different result from what you expected?

Comment: The program stops before the printf("asdf"); and does not execute all of the main() function. That is my current issue. In addition to this, I have no clue where to start for the find_elements function.

Comment: You should 1) Turn on compiler warnings and 2) Find a good book about C.

Comment: You should add all clarification **to the question** instead of writing a comment. Probably your program crashes because you did not allocate memory for `a` and `b`. You should run your program in a debugger to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Before the answer of your question, Welcome to SO. Your code is very incomplete, the question is too broad(smells like you want us to write your code) and there are many catastrophic usages of the language which shows that you are missing a lot of key concepts about the language. I advise you to cross over these key concepts and C Language basics before working on it. Anyways, I am going to try to help you with some problems in your code...

The first thing you are doing wrong is here;

```
int *a;
int *p;
p = a;
```

There is no point to assign an uninitialized pointer to another pointer in your spesific program.

Second thing is that you did not allocate any memory for these pointers `a` and `p`, but you are trying to store user input into these pointers in here;

```
printf("Enter %d numbers: ", n1);
for(p = a; p < a + n1; p++){
    scanf("%d", p);
}
```

And you are applying the same wrong logic in here;

```
int *b;
int *pb;
pb = b;
printf("Enter %d numbers: ", n2);
for(pb = b; pb < b + n2; pb++){
    scanf("%d", pb);
}
```

I don't want to write the code for you, but there is an improvement idea which I can propose to you. You must allocate memory for your pointers before using them like this;

```
int *a = (int *) malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));
```

Now that, you have a pointer named `a` and you allocated a memory block with the size of `n1`, and it is capable to store integer values. You can use it to initialize another pointer or store new integer values in it unless it exceeds the memory block size which you allocated previously.

Comment: I was writing an answer similar and starting to define a proposal of implementation, I let you doing ... if you agree ;-)

Comment: The question is very broad, so there are many things to answer more but I think it is not good to encourage new users to ask broad questions. That's why I only answered about the problematic part of the code. Anyways, feel free to propose your own answer :)

Comment: Thank all of you for the feedback.  I do admit that I am relatively new to Stack Overflow and the language of C.  I have been reading and watching videos on pointers, but they still slightly confuse me.  I am sorry if my question was too broad, next time I will try to narrow it down to a specific point.

Comment: You're welcome. If you liked my answer, you can mark it as the answer of this question.. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

As it is also said in remarks and the other answer the 2 groups

```
int *a;
int *p;
p = a;

int *b;
int *pb;
pb = b;
```

are *problematic* because you just copy not initialized values while you need to allocate memory, and the *scanf* write in unknown addresses

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* fill an array and return it or NULL on error, update sz if ok */
int * init(const char * nth, size_t * sz)
{
  printf("Enter the length of the %s array: ", nth);
  if ((scanf("%d", sz) != 1) || ((*sz) < 1)) {
    puts("invalid size");
    return NULL;
  }

  int * r = malloc((*sz) * sizeof(int));

  if (r == 0) {
    puts("not enough memory");
    return NULL;
  }

  printf("Enter %d numbers: ", *sz);

  int * p;

  for (p = r; p != r + (*sz); ++p) {
    if (scanf("%d", p) != 1) {
      puts("invalid value");
      free(r);
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  return r;
}

/* return 1 if v not in p, else 0 */
int absent(int v, int * p, size_t sz)
{
  int * sup = p + sz;

  while (p != sup)
    if (*p++ == v)
      return 0;

  return 1;
}

/* fill c and return number of values */
size_t find_elements(int *a, int sza, int *b, int szb, int * c)
{
  size_t szc = 0;
  int * pc = c;
  int * p, * sup;

  for (p = a, sup = a + sza; p != sup; ++p) {
    if (absent(*p, b, szb) && absent(*p, c, szc)) {
      *pc++ = *p;
      szc += 1;
    }
  }

  for (p = b, sup = b + szb; p != sup; ++p) {
    if (absent(*p, a, szb) && absent(*p, c, szc)) {
      *pc++ = *p;
      szc += 1;
    }
  }

  return szc;
}

int main()
{
  size_t sza;
  int * a = init("first", &sza);

  if (a == NULL)
    return -1;

  size_t szb;
  int * b = init("second", &szb);

  if (b == NULL)
    return -1;

  /* allocate with the worst case */
  int * c = malloc((sza + szb) * sizeof(int));

  if (c == 0) {
    puts("not enough memory");
    return -1;
  }

  size_t szc = find_elements(a, sza, b, szb, c);

  /* it is possible to use realloc to decrease the allocation size of c */

  for (int * p = c; p != c + szc; ++p)
    printf("%d ", *p);
  putchar('\n');

  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the length of the first array: 3
Enter 3 numbers: 1 2 3
Enter the length of the second array: 4
Enter 4 numbers: 3 2 6 7
1 6 7
```

Under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==5346== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5346== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5346== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5346== Command: ./a.out
==5346== 
Enter the length of the first array: 3
Enter 3 numbers: 1 2 3
Enter the length of the second array: 4
Enter 4 numbers: 3 2 6 7
==5346== Invalid read of size 4
==5346==    at 0x106C8: absent (in /tmp/a.out)
==5346==  Address 0x49d1894 is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==5346==    at 0x4847568: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==5346==    by 0x105C3: init (in /tmp/a.out)
==5346== 
1 6 7 
==5346== 
==5346== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5346==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5346==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 2,104 bytes allocated
==5346== 
==5346== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5346== 
==5346== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5346== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```